# Analysing portion of a photo using python

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, edit, photo

I'm trying to sort pennies based on their darkness or shade. I have a "chamber" where I insert a penny and an rbg photo is taken using the picamera. I then average the the red blue and green using an algorithm that I believe is based on how humans see.  #(0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B).

Anyways, when I analyse the photos RBGs I am also analysing the background and not just the penny in the photo. How can I take the pixels of the penny only and average those?

Can I take a "circular" crop?
Can I somehow detect the penny and edit it into a new photo only involving the penny?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect circular shapes using `Hough Transformation`, as available from `OpenCV`, for example.

See: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

You need to set up the correct parameters for Hough Transformation to only find circles of penny-like size. Should be quite easy task, as your camera has a fixed distance to the penny in the chamber.

Once set up, you *should* find a circle describing the penny on each of your taken photographs. Extract or mask it and keep working using the circular excerpt for your sorting.